# Merge multiple txt files in Excel power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have 500 .txt files. They are recording just one column besides the column header. 
I would like to connect/combine/merge them vertically  and remove the column header...as shown in the pic.
[Multiple txt files to single table/query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdv2t.png)

```
01.txt                 02.txt               03.txt

txt1                    txt2                  txt3   
date_1                 date_2               date_3
a  1                    a  3                 a  5
b  2                    b  4                 b  3 
c  3                    c  2                 c  1
d  4                    d  1                 d  4
```

I want to have a single csv/txt in the end merging these files like so:

```
-Merged.csv(01.txt ;  02.txt ; 03.txt)

        date_1  date_2    date_3
 - a |   1       3         5
 - b |   2       4         3
 - c |   3       2         1
 - d |   4       1         4
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this format better and more clear ? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final try on this one

Use Home...advanced editor... and paste this function into PowerQuery.  Name it:   fnReadFile

```
(zFile)=>
let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(zFile),[Delimiter="#(tab)", Columns=1, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
// Date row includes text "Date: "
DateFind = Text.Replace(Table.FindText(#"Added Index" , "Date"){0}[Column1],"Date: ",""),
// Row preceeding data includes text ">>>"
CaratFind = Table.FindText(#"Added Index" , ">>>"){0}[Index],
FilterDate=Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [Index] > CaratFind),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(FilterDate, "Date", each DateFind),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", Int64.Type}})
in #"Changed Type"
```

Use Home...advanced editor... and paste this query into PowerQuery after changing the first row to your appropriate directory.  It will read in all .txt files and combine them as desired based on function above

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\directory\subdirectory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".txt")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Custom", each fnReadFile([Folder Path]&"\"&[Name])),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Date"}, {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Date"}),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Date"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"[Date]), "Date", "Column1.2")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: thanks so much, it worked like magic. 
(I will try to understand the conceppt a bit better and make a video on it) 

Thank you again!

Comment: Happy to help but no idea why we need a video. I am not here to write code for your youtube acccount